# How to Add MVC Views in Orchard CMS Custom Module

Tags: orchardcms

When I am creating a custom module containing my own Controllers and Views, the default project created by Code Generation creates a project that is like MVC but Visual Studio does not recognize it as an MVC project so it doesn't offer the normal "Add View" tooling as it does in a "real" MVC project.

I have seen posts talking about changing the Project type GUID in the project file but I am hoping there is an alternative to this approach.  I have also seen tutorials where the presenter is using Resharper.  I am currently not a Resharper user so I am not ready to adopt this approach either.

Are there project templates available?  Any Code Generation module features I can take advantage of?  I mainly want to find out how people are doing this now to make the development workflow go faster.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's what the code generation tool does, so that we can reduce the Orchard requirements just to ASP.NET 4. Now a module is just a project and a manifest, living in a subfolder of Modules. There is nothing magical about the command-line and it's perfectly fine to create the project from VS. Or you can modify the code generation command so it adds the project type guid at creation. Both choices are valid, you just need to be aware that if there are other users than yourself, you might prevent them from opening the module in VS unless they install the MVC tooling first. That should not be a big problem, but just something to be aware of.